# Ревью кода перед отправкой в репозитории заказчика

Tags: svn

Организую аутсорс. Код в конечном итоге комитится в СВН репозиторий зказчика. Есть несколько программистов 2-3, перед тем как их код попадет в репозиторий заказчика он должен быть проверен тимлидом. Для этого предполагаю поднять свой СВН сервер в который и будут комитить программисты.  Как лучше организовать процедуру обновления своего репозитория из репозитория заказчика (код в репозитории заказчика меняется другими командами) и комит своих изменений в репозиторий заказчика?

Comment: Рекомендую вам подумать насчет Git и github-flow. Там предусмотрена возможность ревью во время запроса на слияние (pull request).

Comment: И да, выразивший "свое мнение" минусатор - был не прав: хотя предварительного обдумывания решения и нет, вопрос насущен и решение его достаточно небесполезно сторонней аудитории

Comment: @tsprof SVN подразумевает использование одного центрального репозитория, и любые схемы с двумя репозиториями и синхронизацией будут слишком хрупкими. Насколько критично использование SVN со стороны заказчика, и со стороны команды? Можно ли использовать Git, хотя бы для внутрикомандной работы? Синхронизацию из Git в SVN, особенно одностороннюю, настроить достаточно просто.

Comment: К сожалению, на стороне заказчика уже используется SVN и поменять его на что-то другое нет возможности. На стороне команды можно использовать Git или что-то другое без проблем.  Думаю Git+двухсторонняя синхронизация это решение, спасибо!